# Can I bind two arrow keys to a single shortcut?

Tags: keyboard, macos

I'd like to be able to bind a shortcut key to perform differently when pressing two arrow keys than when pressing one or the other. For instance, I want to make a new shortcut key for <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> that will be different from <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>.

Is this possible?

I'm using OS X 10.9 - Mavericks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) like this with KeyRemap4MacBook:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>test</name>
    <identifier>test</identifier>
    <autogen>__SimultaneousKeyPresses__
    KeyCode::CURSOR_UP,
    MODIFIERFLAG_EITHER_LEFT_OR_RIGHT_COMMAND | ModifierFlag::NONE,
    KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT,
    MODIFIERFLAG_EITHER_LEFT_OR_RIGHT_COMMAND | ModifierFlag::NONE,
    KeyCode::F19</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

Then use F19 as the shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

On your keyboard you have 2 kind of keys :

- Normal keys, which you can't combine
- Modifier keys, which you can combine.

<kbd>Up</kbd>, <kbd>left</kbd>, <kbd>down</kbd> or <kbd>right</kbd> aren't modifiers whereas <kbd>Cmd</kbd>, <kbd>Option</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> are.

So no you won't be able to do it.

Comment: This does describe the stock behavior, but there are many ways to augment that with assistive devices, scripting, changing the key mapping, etc...