# Bind a single arrow keypress to multiple arrow keypresses

Tags: macos, keyboard, keybindings, karabiner

I'm trying to bind the Up arrow to three Left arrows done in rapid (instant) succession (although I'd also be interested in knowing how to put some fixed delay as well).

There are two existing answers on this and both are either out-dated or cannot be adapted for my purposes.

1. [Can I bind two arrow keys to a single shortcut?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114743/can-i-bind-two-arrow-keys-to-a-single-shortcut)
2. [How to bind a key to press two separate keys](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/224861/how-to-bind-a-key-to-press-two-separate-keys)

The first link proposes "KeyRemap4MacBook" which has been superseded by Karabiner and the original instructions don't apply to the current version. The second answer uses Karabiner, but references a private.xml file which does not exist in the current version of Karabiner. It's been superseded by a private .json file.

I have messed around with a private .json file, but it's not clear how to repeat the same arrow press using a Karabiner macro, and there aren't abundant examples online attempting something similar.

My attempt at achieving this:

```
"rules": [
    {  "description": "Call it whatever you like…",
       "manipulators": [ {
                "type": "basic",
                "from": {
                    "key_code": "up_arrow",
              },
              "to": [
                  {
                      "key_code": "left_arrow",
                      "key_code": "left_arrow",
                      "key_code": "left_arrow"

                  }
              ]
          }]
```

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes solutions are ***sooooooo*** simple …
Just grant each "key_code" a pair of brackets ***of its own*** – like this:

```
 "to": [
        {"key_code": "left_arrow"},
        {"key_code": "left_arrow"},
        {"key_code": "left_arrow",
           "repeat": false }
        ]
```

… and your code will run easily.

`"repeat": false` *(last key_code!) constricts left-arrows to "only once" even if held down.*